# C# 2010　最小化時のフォーム座標を取得

Tags: c#

最小化時のフォーム座標を保存したいのですが、
下のコードを実行すると座標がマイナス値になってしまいます。

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e);

    if(this.WindowState == FormWindowState.Minimized)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(this.Location.ToString());
    }
}
```

最小化する直前の座標を取得するためにはどうすればよいでしょうか。

Comment: 参考までに座標を取得したい理由は何でしょうか？

Comment: 次回起動時のために座標を保存することに使います。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 次回起動時のために座標を保存する

「最小化する直前の座標」だけでなく最大化する直前の座標や、マルチモニタ環境でどのモニタに表示されていたのかなども考慮が必要です。更に次回起動時にモニタサイズが縮小されていると画面外に溢れたりなども考慮が必要です。

C#ではありませんがWindows APIの[`GetWindowPlacement`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowplacement)を使うとこの辺り一式の値が取得でき、更に[`SetWindowPlacement`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowplacement)を使うと一気に復元できます。C#からは`DllImport`を使用して呼び出し可能です。

Answer (score 0):

信用度が足りないのでコメントできないため、こちらで追加情報を書きます。

ssayuriさんがリンクを張られている所から、[`tagWINDOWPLACEMENT`構造体](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/ns-winuser-tagwindowplacement)へジャンプできます。そこには、次のように書かれています。

```
typedef struct tagWINDOWPLACEMENT {
  UINT  length;
  UINT  flags;
  UINT  showCmd;
  POINT ptMinPosition;
  POINT ptMaxPosition;
  RECT  rcNormalPosition;
  RECT  rcDevice;
} WINDOWPLACEMENT;
```

P/INVOKEをするためにはこの構造体をC#で定義しなければなりませんが、そのとき`rcDevice`を含めると、`SetWindowPlacement`が期待したように動作しません。`FALSE`を返すわけではないのですが、ウィンドウ位置が変わらない、という現象になりました。
上記の通りの構造体だとサイズが60バイトになりますが、`GetWindowPlacement`で取得した（取得によって情報が書き換わった）構造体は、`length`プロパティが44でした。`rcDevice`を定義から外して、サイズが44バイトの構造体を渡すと、期待通りに動作しました。もし、`SetWindowPlacement`で`TRUE`が返ってくるのにウィンドウ位置が変わらない場合は、これを疑ってみてください。
（Windows 10 Build1709で確認）

Comment: `WinUser.h`を確認してもらえばわかりますが、`rcDevice`メンバーは`_MAC`用で、Windowsでは使われていません。

Answer (score 0):

this.LocationはOnResizeイベントでなくても取得できると思います。
美しくはないですが、例えばタイマー等で取得し、マイナスでない場合は
採用し、マイナスの場合は捨てる等の処理を行うこともできます。